# ListView Button Color Change

Tags: javascript, html, button, listviewitem

I am coding a basic website by using C# on Visual Studio. I have buttons which are a member of ListView. I want to change the color of the last clicked button to identify which is pressed last. This is the button code block of ListView:

```
`<asp:LinkButton  ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CssClass="button-row"  Text='<%# Eval("NameofColumn") %>' CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("IDofColumn") %>' />`
```

I tried to implement some javascript functions but it did not work. Also i see people who are using this: `OnClientClick="changeColor(this);` code block in ListView button. However it did not work either.